# Sliding Menu example not working : java.lang.IllegalStateException: RandomList must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, exception, sliding, slidingmenu

I downloaded Sliding Menu library and Actionsbarsherlock from [Links](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), I found out example of it from [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/goygnl614vx2guw/SlidingMenuExample.zip), which had an YouTube video  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rs9mSnWDlZo) to show the working. I followed all the steps, but when I am running the code, its giving me.

```
 05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rufflez.slidingmenuexample/com.rufflez.slidingmenuexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RandomList must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity.
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RandomList must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity.
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment.onAttach(SherlockListFragment.java:25)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:867)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
05-28 15:41:21.665: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     ... 11 more
```

No idea why the error is coming, I have add both libraries also.

[image: libraries added]

Comment: Are you having difficulty in running library samples or using this library in your own project?

Comment: in samples, testing samples first..

Answer (score 2):

**Issue:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RandomList must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity
```

**Solution:**

you need to extend SherlockActivity

**Reference:**

Have a look at [SlidingMenu usage guide](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) ,

read last point of Step 2 inside section of **How to Integrate this Library into Your Projects**

"If you want to use another library such as ActionBarSherlock, you can just change the SlidingActivities to extend the SherlockActivities instead of the regular Activities"

**Explaination:**

[image]

As shown in above screenshot,

`SlidingActivity extends SherlockActivity`.

Similarly following changes are required,

```
 - SlidingListActivity extends SherlockListActivity
 - SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
 - SlidingPreferenceActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity
```

**Note:**
Don't forget to add `actionbarsherlock` library to your SlidingMenu's library to access `SherlockActivity`.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: This was exactly the right answer for me. Seems odd to me that the instructions require you to modify the library you just downloaded, but there you are. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in two steps:

1. Add `actionbarsherlock` library to `SlidingMenu` library as well.
2. Open `com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity` and extend it from `SherlockFragmentActivity`
   .